# Why doesn't integration flow subscribe to the from channel?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

To me, this appears to be just about the simplest possible spring integration example. I'm trying to learn from the [si4demo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/dsl/si4demo/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/si4demo/dsl/Application.java). But when I run it, I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has
>   no subscribers for channel 'application.inbox'.; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException:
>   Dispatcher has no subscribers

Where am I going wrong? Doesn't the defined flow create a subscription to the inbox channel?

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.IntegrationComponentScan;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args)) {

            final Gateway gateway = ctx.getBean(Gateway.class);
            final String rs = gateway.send("hullo");
            System.out.println(rs);

        }

    }

    private static final String INBOX = "inbox";

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = INBOX)
    public interface Gateway {
        String send(String msg);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(INBOX)
                .transform(p -> "world")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean(name = INBOX)
    public MessageChannel inbox() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have missed the main player - `@EnableIntegraion`:

> Starting with version 4.0, the `@EnableIntegration` annotation has been introduced, to allow the registration of Spring Integration infrastructure beans (see JavaDocs). This annotation is required when only Java & Annotation configuration is used, e.g. with Spring Boot and/or Spring Integration Messaging Annotation support and Spring Integration Java DSL with no XML integration configuration.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: i especially appreciate the link to TFM!